# Not able to separate the elements from xml contents fetched from a URL in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have fetched the contents from a url using CURL which is in the form of XML. But i want to separate the contents in the form of variables which i tried doing using "simplexml_load_string".
My contents from the url are:-

```
 <GetGPSRawDataResponse xmlns="http://example.org/">
    <GetGPSRawDataResult>
    [{"IMIENO":"35xxxxxxxxxxx","Lattitude":24.4286285,"Longitude":73.0507245,"Altitude":0.000,"Speed":0.000,"CTime":"Jul 8 2015 7:24:02:000PM","RecordTime":"Jul 9 2015 8:46AM","DevDistance":0.1000,"CardID":""},{"IMIENO":"35xxxxxxxxxx","Lattitude":24.4286285,"Longitude":73.0507245,"Altitude":0.000,"Speed":0.000,"CTime":"Jul 8 2015 7:19:02:000PM","RecordTime":"Jul 9 2015 8:49AM","DevDistance":0.0950,"CardID":""}]
    </GetGPSRawDataResult></GetGPSRawDataResponse>
```

I tried fetching the contents from the xml like:-

```
$abc=get_data($url);//get_data is a function that is working to fetch url contents
//After fetching the above contents from the url.
I did $xml_retrieve=simplexml_load_string($abc);
```

but the $xml returns nothing. I dont understand why? I want to get the latitude and longitude from the above contents But I dont understand where m i doing wrong if this is the only way

Answer (score 0):

HAving never used simplxml I do not know for sure but it looks like all you have done is load the xml to create the reference to the simplexml object. I think you need to use another method on `$xml_retrieve` to get the actual data that you want.

From the manual it states that simplexml_load_string:

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing
>   the data held within the xml document.

I tried playing around with simple_xml but could not get the xpath method to work so reverted to using standard the DOMDocument.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->loadXML( $get_data( $url ) );
libxml_clear_errors();

/* Get the node in the document you need */
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('GetGPSRawDataResult');
$node=$col->item(0);
/* decode response */
$o=json_decode( $node->nodeValue );
/*Get first item from array */
$j=$o[0];

/* do whatever you need with each of the constituent pieces from the json data */
echo 'IMIENO='.$j->IMIENO.' Lattitude='.$j->Lattitude.' Longitude='.$j->Longitude;
```

Comment: ? Check in the manual ( php ) on your system - seems very strange that DOMDocument isn't there  as it is part of the PHP core functionality.